# Which cipher is used in this UDP stream?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I'm trying to analyze a stream of communication I captured from a game. I know the keys but I don't know how to apply them.

I've tried:

- Various AES-256 modes, splitting the message at different offsets into (nonce, ciphertext, MAC)
- RC4
- Debug the client binary for hints

But to no avail. The modes with MAC tell me it's wrong, those that don't just produce data where I can't find any structure - for example no ascii strings which I'd expect (e.g. names of open online games).

I see there is some structure to the messages (see below) but I don't know how to proceed. Do you have any hints?

#### Communication flow

The communication is first set up with a HTTPS login. The server returns first a block of 256 bytes (different on each login), then a JSON.

[image]

Example of JSON obtained at login:

```
{
  "gameid": "2",
  "userid": ...,
  "login": "...",
  "password": "",
  "avatar": "avatars/user/male1.png",
  "email": "...",
  "sex": "Male",
  "color": "green",
  "rank": 1,
  "rank_score": 0,
  "score_to_next_rank": 400,
  "score_to_prev_rank": 0,
  "top_percents": "100",
  "ext_accounts": {},
  "last_ack_msg": 85,
  "custom_data": "{}",
  "version": "475",
  "api_version": "475",
  "server_version": 472,
  "db_version": 42,
  "client_changed": false,
  "token_client": "...",    // these two values
  "token_onetime": "...",   // are repeated from login
  "products": "",
  "server_addresses": {
    "0": {
      "type": "ipv4",
      "host": "...",
      "port": 4001
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "ipv6",
      "host": "...",
      "port": ...
    }
  },
  "client_to_server_key": "taxQ0K3NshjkYLqZI5/irD3c+RdtL3tqY7+PFWPy2B0=",
  "server_to_client_key": "uavWc36jxIiWNQjcZ3aAkUJQIL8mrXjWdtSt8X5gB4Y=",
  "timeoutMinimum": 5000,
  "ping": 60000
}
```

Therefore, the key size seems to be **256 bits** and the two streams are encrypted independently.

What follows is a two-way communication with the servers mentioned in `server_addresses`. The smallest packet payload is **26 bytes** and can come from either the server or from the client. If the payload is greater than 1400, it gets split into multiple packets that just follow each other.

[image]

#### Example messages

##### Smallest messages client -> server

```
e310ffbd10c82835ebea08755582d1c09b3333cb05f635c55140

e310ff4210c82835ea16c1db715a1447815db9ecaf9d5d3182db

e310ff4210c3283ed82de0ec5dc56f6462ea6732fb5425e305e0

e310ff4210cb2836d43624a2832672c34f9b409bfca0545e6a5e52be7375c66c9a38

e310ff4210cd2830d47124a2832072c54fdc23be383613565a653775d9c16c3e9c00
```

##### Larger messages client -> server

```
6310fdfe96c92836750f227a8225729bee30c34435b0f8e4726177eb5cc55d15523ccdcac0aa4ace5f8e27014be56c7c30db61cc0cfaf5d2c09069e5f0da3d8df2d53ce4f32e3b519abc705a09e17590b55a2e9f42113a55b08762262c705d4321ca94caa57655ed87873521e0f23135ad4d221cd43a519f09ec5f1bde8997805dd7d52f4fd1dea59dc8c7e119def980ebdd537a7a6522f8ae8255e4cf7732ae908d1c87d54f4b9a25dbe84aed

6310f5b696c928377527227a8225729cee30eb4435b0f8e47c8a5a81fef32f8621a5bf89076f074d2a98f2535f3ca51c99710d5c4489677c9252bf5ed9c0d8e25146b2a779153104e267b49c514dd6b3fb1a672b4308f24153847768738b7eeb3698007639b82361571fb52c84831ade0552adcaa56590c178941ec677bf176823321f4bc670d265aa0689d5d28240d8a4dbd273962854d9f1d4208ead8f245d3691137e07b1d82814351397eb5e2812eeb3f921ae274dc099a5f82efe581d1b2fd670ebb0856a18cf8cad4093c2f97621cfd936d1
```

##### Smallest messages server -> client

```
e94c040c19bf6bf452308e078fb71acf17a04e4e299de404c997

e94c040c19bc6bf7502fb66454186c10a632bbc1cfc8ef65b3bd

e94c040c19bd6bf65867888c85ec4d926f7ffb7df531ed3e7c3c
```

##### Larger messages server -> client

I picked a few messages of the same length that are similar to each other. Especially the last two differ only in the header and footer. The sequence numbers of the packets are 187, 300 and 302 respectively. Therefore, the last two messages may be just some retransmission and the conserved text may be the actual ciphertext. However, they're strangely similar to the first one - #187 - except a few bytes. There were about 5 seconds between message 187 and 300.

```
694ca81e9fbe6bfd5338dac820f9ac0976d799d3020840000861fdbb7ae642ef33ea4c4ac3996703d2acd7f5bbfed67951deb8761c4d781d0fde7604040b11b5df68eeaa9d89079ce35ed6771f97eb970c2f5330b2a419eb22f81a8e0278b644b696afc62d92fcfa66afae5f17fb34e218eb56a001a27cd6ab163b6fa1a325177d1a71979a78cc400d8f018082c387efa50691bb1665da63ffa82f16b3ccc7ff157f03a4ea1e0d0334fbc998449a07a37058b8cc58921ac9374ecf5631f19bf60c1fa5188b

694cbaa29fbe6bfe5338dac820f9ac0876d799d3020840000861fdbb7ae642ef33ea4c4ac3996703d2acd7f5bbfed67951deb8761c4d781d0fde7604040b11b5df68eeaa9d89079ce35ed6771f97eb970c2f5330b2a419eb22f81a8e0278b644b696afc62d92fcfa66affe3f7fcb34e218eb56a001a27cd6ab163b6fa1a325177d1a71979a78cc400d8f018082c387efa50691bb1665da63ffa82f16b3ccc7ff157f03a4ea1e8d0434fbc998449a07a37058c0cc6428ca785cfe5458532a73e9e063715eba

694cc7d99fbe6bfe5338dac820f9ac0876d799d3020840000861fdbb7ae642ef33ea4c4ac3996703d2acd7f5bbfed67951deb8761c4d781d0fde7604040b11b5df68eeaa9d89079ce35ed6771f97eb970c2f5330b2a419eb22f81a8e0278b644b696afc62d92fcfa66affe3f7fcb34e218eb56a001a27cd6ab163b6fa1a325177d1a71979a78cc400d8f018082c387efa50691bb1665da63ffa82f16b3ccc7ff157f03a4ea1e8d0434fbc998449a07a37058c0cc644060b1f2bd4ebedae33dee1f125d212f
```